# Continuous CSS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a way to continuously animate a background image's `background-position` property using CSS3 transitions?

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS transitions only solution or are you fine with CSS animations?

Comment: The main idea is to use a large background image as  slider. So i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it's possible - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/djsSq/1/)

```css
div
{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    -webkit-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
            animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}​

@-moz-keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}

@keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}
```

​

Comment: Id there a way to do this with background color? Fading from red to blue to yellow continuously? Great example by the way. It should be the answer here op.

Comment: I managed to figure this out myself using your code as a basis: http://jsfiddle.net/YSYRe/ Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with the whole div instead the background? Or do I need javascript for this?

Comment: @ChazyChaz You'll probably need JS for that. There is no `background-repeat` for `div`-s, so you'll have to clone your `div` and move them with JS

Comment: Yes, but in the end I managed to workaround it with php, printing the variable (the one that contains the childs) two times, then wait for the repeated content to reach the start and that's when it starts again, it creates the illusion of continuously.