# HW accelerated CSS properties other than transform

Tags: css

I have an element with a repeated background image, then I animate the background position so my background moves indefinitely, then I'm happy because I got the desired effect.
But then happiness vanishes when I hear my PC fan getting loud and when I check my CPU usage and it's very high.

Is there a way to get hardware acceleration for CSS properties other that transform with the famous `translate3d(0,0,0)`?
If not, can I achieve the same effect with some kind of hack with `transform: translate(...)`?
Finally if this can't be done with CSS I could accept a canvas solution. its a repeated pattern moving in the top-right to bottom-left direction.

Comment: consuming much CPU depends much on the ***specific*** effect and also on the browser you are using. I guess you are using FireFox, right?

Comment: Take a look at this previously answered question: [Continuous CSS transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224047/continuous-css-transitions) [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/djsSq/1/)

Comment: I get high cpu usage in both firefox and chrome(but higher on ff :P).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `keyframes` with CSS `animation` this can be accomplished easily. This solution only involves creating one extra column of your background images and will cut down on your CPU load. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/WX6Sc/)

Animation CSS:

```css
-webkit-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
        animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
```

Keyframes CSS (with 100px standing in as the width of your individual background images):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}

@keyframes slide
{
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    100% {background-position: 100px 0;}
}
```